In Exodus 1:15, is there a reason that the names of the midwives are specified?
Q: In Exodus 1:15, is there a reason that the names of the midwives are specified?:

15The king of Egypt spoke to the Hebrew midwives, one of whom was named Shiphrah and the other Puah, 16saying, “When you deliver the Hebrew women, look at the birthstool: if it is a boy, kill him; if it is a girl, let her live.” 17The midwives, fearing God, did not do as the king of Egypt had told them; they let the boys live. 18So the king of Egypt summoned the midwives and said to them, “Why have you done this thing, letting the boys live?” 19The midwives said to Pharaoh, “Because the Hebrew women are not like the Egyptian women: they are vigorous. Before the midwife can come to them, they have given birth.” 20And God dealt well with the midwives; and the people multiplied and increased greatly. 21And because the midwives feared God, He established households for them. 22Then Pharaoh charged all his people, saying, “Every boy that is born you shall throw into the Nile, but let every girl live.”

Jewish Publication Society. (1985). Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures (Ex 1:15–22). Jewish Publication Society.
Is there something in the etymology of the names? Do we know of them in other contexts? Or do they tell us something about people with whom they are connected?

Shifrah: This was Jochebed, [called Shifrah] because she beautified [מְשַׁפֶּרֶת] the newborn infant. [From Sotah 11b]
Puah: This was Miriam, [called Puah] because she cried (פּוֹעָה) and talked and cooed to the newborn infant in the manner of women who soothe a crying infant. פּוֹעָה is an expression of crying out, similar to “Like a travailing woman will I cry (אֶפְעֶה) " (Isa. 42:14). Rashi on Sotah 11b explains that she played with the infant to soothe and amuse him.

Thank you, @rosends. That would work for an answer for me if you care to post it as such. Thanks.

@rosends That explains the names, but I'm not sure it explains why their names are mentioned.

@shmosel it seems that radhi's point is that they aren't simply being named but being described.

Indeed, it seems they are mentioned in order we should learn these points

@RabbiKaii Learn what? They're describing standard procedure.

According to the Midrash Shemos Rabba 1:13 the names are given to express merits of the two women in saving lives of the Jewish children. Their effort is truely remarkable because only because of them and other righteous women we had true shvatim coming out of the Egyptian bondage.

“The king of Egypt said to the Hebrew midwives, of whom the name of one was Shifra and the name of the other was Pu’a” (Exodus 1:15).
When he saw that they were procreating, he issued a decree against the males  – that is what is written: “The king of Egypt said to the midwives….” Who were the midwives? Rav said: A daughter-in-law and her mother-in-law, Yokheved and Elisheva daughter of Aminadav. Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥman says: A woman and her daughter, Yokheved and Miriam.
And Miriam was no more than five years old, as Aaron was three years older than Moses. Our Rabbis, of blessed memory, said: She would go with her mother Yokheved and assist her, and she was very quick. While the child is still young, his [character] is recognizable. That is what Solomon said: “Even a lad is recognized through his deeds” (Proverbs 20:11).
“…the name of one was Shifra [and the name of the other was Pu’a],” because she would attend to [meshaperet] the baby when he would emerge covered in blood; “Pu’a,” because she would express [nofa’at] wine into the babies after her mother [had attended to them].
Alternatively, Shifra, because Israel procreated [sheparu veravu] in her day; Pu’a, who would revive [mapia] the baby when they would say it was dead.
Alternatively, Shifra, because she made her actions pleasing [shipera] before God; Pu’a, because she caused Israel to appear [hofia] before God. Alternatively, Pu’a, because she was impudent [hofia panim] to Pharaoh and had her nose in the air toward him, and she said to him: ‘Woe unto that man when God will come and punish him.’ He became filled with fury and sought to kill her. Shifra, because she eased [meshaperet] the words of her daughter and placated him toward her. She said to him: ‘Are you paying attention to her? She is a child and knows nothing.’
Rabbi Ḥanina bar Rav Yitzḥak said: Shifra, because she preserved Israel for God, and it was for their sake that the heavens were created, regarding which it is written: “By his wind the heavens are calm [shifra]” (Job 26:13). Pu’a, because she was impudent [hofia panim] toward her father. Amram was the head of the Sanhedrin at that time. Once Pharaoh issued his decree and said: “Every son that is born you shall cast him into the Nile” (Exodus 1:22), Amram said: ‘Isn’t Israel begetting children for naught?’ Immediately, he separated from Yokheved and abstained from sexual relations. He divorced his wife when she was three months pregnant. All Israel arose and divorced their wives. His daughter said to him: ‘Your decree is harsher than Pharaoh’s, as Pharaoh decreed only against the males, and you, against the males and the females. Pharaoh is wicked and it is uncertain whether his decree will be fulfilled or whether it will not be fulfilled. However, you are righteous and your decree will be fulfilled.’ He arose and remarried his wife. All Israel arose and remarried their wives. That is Pu’a, who was impudent toward her father.

Another midrash Koheles Rabba 7.1.3 recounts the deeds of the midwives and gives the punchline that OP is asking about:

Rabbi Yehuda said: Miriam and Yokheved were the midwives of the Israelites. As it is written: “The name of one was Shifra and the name of the second was Pu’a” (Exodus 1:15). Shifra, this is Yokheved, who would tend to [mishaperet] the children. Alternatively, it is because she procreated [shepara verava]. Alternatively, it is because the Israelites procreated due to her. Alternatively, it is because they bettered [shiperu] [the Israelite women] with mitzvot and good deeds. Alternatively, Shifra [is the name given her] as praise [of her character], as it is stated: “With His breath the heavens were calmed [shifra]” (Job 26:13).
Pu’a, this is Miriam, as she would make a comforting sound [po’a] to the woman, and the child would emerge. Alternatively, Pu’a, as she would cry [po’a] and weep over her brother Moses who was cast into the Nile, as it is stated: “His sister stood at a distance” (Exodus 2:4). Alternatively, Pu’a, as she revealed [hofia] the actions of her brother. Alternatively, as she stood boldly [pa’at] before Pharaoh and said to him: ‘Woe to you on the Day of Judgment.’
It is taught: A man is called by three names; one that his father and his mother called him, one that others called him, and one that he is called in the book of his lineage.


Don Yitzchak Abarbanel (ad loc) explains that midwifery consisted of a pair, with each midwife possessing a unique and complementary skill.
He explains that 'Shifra' and 'Puah' were not proper names but rather were terms that denoted these specific skillsets (similar to Chazal).

והנה המילדות א"א שנאמר שהיו שתים בלבד כי איך יספיקו שתי נשים לעם כבד ועצום כבני ישראל ואין לומר שהיו שתים אלא שרות המילדות כלן כדברי המפרשים כי היה ראוי שיקראם הכתוב שרות המילדות כמו שר המשקים ושר האופים ושר הטבחים גם כי מה הועיל פרעה בתקנתו לדבר זה לשרות ההנה אם לא יצוה כן למשרתות שלהן וגם שלא צוה להן שתצוינה זה למילדו' אשר תחתיהן אלא שהענין כך הוא שהיה מנהג במצרים שהיו באות שתים מילדות לעמוד עם כל אשה שהיתה יולדת והאחת מהן היה עסקה בהוצאת הולד ובשכלולו ולכן נקראת שפרה ע"ש שמשפיר' את הולד. והשנית היה עסקה להחזיק ביולדת ולעוזרה בדברים וקולות ותפלות ולכן נקראת פועה מלשון כיולדה אפעה.
ואמר שדבר פרעה למילדות העבריות – ר"ל לכולנה כי לא אמר לשתי המילדו' אלא לפי שלכל המילדו' הרבות ההנה דבר וצוה זה וכלן היו נחלקות לשתי אומניות ההם וזה אמרו ששם האחת שפרה ושם השנית פועה. ולא היו עבריות כי איך יבטח לבו בנשים העבריות שימיתו ולדיהן אבל היו מצריות מילדות את העבריות ר"ל עוזרות אותן ללדת כמ"ש בילדכן את העבריות.
"And behold, the midwives cannot be said to be only two, for how could two women suffice for such a heavy and numerous people as the children of Israel? And one cannot say that there were only two, for the midwives were all in charge, as explained by the commentators, for it would have been fitting for the text to call them the head midwives, like the cupbearer, the baker, and the chief cook. Moreover, what benefit did Pharaoh gain from this decree to speak of the head midwives if he did not command this also for their servants? And he did not command them to kill the children that were under them. Rather, the matter is such that there was a custom in Egypt for two midwives to come to attend to each woman giving birth, one of whom was occupied with delivering the child and assisting it, and therefore she was called Shifra, because she beautifies the birth. The second was responsible for holding the mother and assisting her with words and cries and prayers, and thus she was called Puah, from the language of ‘to help the birthing woman.’
And it is said that Pharaoh spoke to the Hebrew midwives—meaning to all of them—because he did not say to the two midwives, but rather to all the many midwives, that this is what he commanded and all of them were divided into those two professions. This is why it is said that the name of one was Shifra and the name of the second was Puah. And they were not Hebrew women, for how could he trust his heart in Hebrew women that they would kill their children? Rather, they were Egyptian women who assisted the Hebrews, meaning they helped them to give birth, as it is said, ‘when you help the Hebrew women.’"

(There is considerable dispute amongst the commentaries as to if the midwives were Jewish or not.
Don Abarbanel holds that they were not, see Shadal at length)

Oh, I like that explanation. I'm not qualified to say which is "true," but to me, that makes a great deal of sense. Thanks.
